# Multidimensional arrays - PYTHON

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

i have problems with the array indexes in python.
at function readfile it crashes and prints: **"list index out of range"**

```
inputarr        = []

def readfile(filename):
    lines = readlines(filename)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        i = 0
        j= 0
        k = 0
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            if not line == '':
                inputarr[j][k] = line
                k += 1
                #print("\tnew entry\tj=%d\tk=%d" % (j, k))
            elif line == '':
                k = 0
                j += 1
                #print("new block!\tj=%d\tk=%d" % (j, k))
            i += 1
            processing(i, lines)
```

Comment: You can't index into a list of length 0. You'll need to append elements to it. You might also want to look into numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is due to you trying to assign to an index of `inputarr` that is outside the bounds of the list. This causes an error in python (unlike some other languages like javascript which automatically extend an array if you try to access an index that is outside the initial bounds of the array).

You need to either pre-fill `inputarr` so it has the right shape and size, or you need to dynamically create it as you go.  I prefer the latter:

```
inputarr = [[]]
#           ^^  Set up the first row
def readfile(filename):
    lines = readlines(filename)
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        i = 0
        j= 0
        k = 0
        for line in f:
            line = line.rstrip("\n")
            if not line == '':
                inputarr[j].append(line)
#                          ^^^^^^^^       Add a new value to the end of the current row of inputarr
                k += 1
                #print("\tnew entry\tj=%d\tk=%d" % (j, k))
            elif line == '':
                k = 0
                inputarr.append([])
#               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  Add a new blank row to inputarr
                j += 1
                #print("new block!\tj=%d\tk=%d" % (j, k))
            i += 1
            processing(i, lines)
```

Comment: You're welcome.  If this solved your problem, consider marking it "accepted" so future readers can easily tell.

Comment: ah okay, i forgot, it's my first own post... until now, i've already found all i wanted to knew but not in this case...

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `inputarr` is empty. For example:

```
lst = []
lst[0] = 1 // error
```

In your case:

```
inputarr = []
j = 0
...
inputarr[j][k] = line   // inputarr= []; j = 0; so inputarr[0] = ...!ERROR
```